# Terraform to split the input before provisioning

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I'm working on creating the repos using terraform. The git repo input is passing as a list to terraform.tfvars as given below

repo_list = ["Test-Repo1","Dev-Repo2","Prod_Repo3"]

i'm using the below configuration language to provision the repos

```
resource "azuredevops_git_repository" "test" {
  count = length(var.repo_list )
  project_id = azuredevops_project.proj.id
  name       = var.repo_list[count.index]
  initialization {
  init_type = "Clean"
 }
}
```

With the above configuration i'm able to provision the repo with the name as given in the repo_list. But i'm looking to split the repo name using the delimiter "-". So if i'm giving "Test-Repo4" then i should able to split it and pass the value "Repo4" to above configuration and Repo4 should get created. But as per the current setup Test-Repo4 repo will get created.

I'm new to Terraform. So  ready to restructure my code based on the suggestions . The reason why i'm using the "ENV_REPO" is because i'm performing the serious of functions in batch script based on this value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use split function and then element function to select proper value. Please check below snippet:

```
resource "azuredevops_git_repository" "test" {
  count = length(var.repo_list )
  project_id = azuredevops_project.proj.id
  name       = "${element(split("-", var.repo_list[count.index]), 1)}"
  initialization {
  init_type = "Clean"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Krzysztof
your solution works perfectly.

Just for my knowledge  , how i can make use of terraform locals here?

Comment: You can use locals in the same way as variables. Just use `local.some_name`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer (both are valid!), if you know that your names will *always* be structured into two parts like that, and the two parts each have a fixed meaning, then you could use [the `regex` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/regex.html) to unpack them into a map that might make the meaning clearer to future readers:

```
locals {
  repositories = tomap({
    for name in var.repo_list :
    name => regex("^(?P<environment>\\w)-(?P<repository>\\w)$")
  })
}

resource "azuredevops_git_repository" "test" {
  for_each = local.repositories

  project_id = azuredevops_project.proj.id
  name       = each.value.repository
  initialization {
    init_type = "Clean"
  }
}
```

This regular expression pattern uses named capture groups, and so the result will be a map whose keys are the capture group names. For your input (assuming you meant to use the `-` separator for all three examples) `local.repositories` would be:

```
tomap({
  Test-Repo1 = tomap({
    environment = "Test"
    repository  = "Repo1"
  })
  Dev-Repo2 = tomap({
    environment = "Dev"
    repository  = "Repo2"
  })
  Prod-Repo3 = tomap({
    environment = "Prod"
    repository  = "Repo3"
  })
})
```

My tradeoff here is that I'd rather see `.environment` and `.repository` when referring to this elsewhere in configuration, as opposed to `[0]` and `[1]`, so that the intent is easier to understand. However, this does come at the cost of a non-trivial regular expression pattern that might be hard to read itself, so I think this would be worthwhile only if you're unlikely to often refer to or maintain that regular expression pattern in particular.